# JQuery animation callbacks

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I have a simple page that animates a box back and forth using 2 functions: animateLeft and animateRight.  When I call the animation this way, it works fine:

```
$("#divTestBox3").animate({ "left" : "200px" }, 1000, animateLeft);
```

However, when I call it this way:

```
$("#divTestBox3").animate({ "left" : "200px" }, 1000, animateLeft());
```

the function animateLeft() does not wait until after the animation is complete before it executes.  animateLeft() is called immediately, resulting in a stack overflow.  Can someone help me understand the difference between these two lines and why they behave differently.

The full application is shown below.

```
<head>
<script src="../JSCommon/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"   type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

   var stop = false;

   $(document).keydown(function(event) {
      stop = !stop;
      if (!stop)
         animateRight();        
   });

   function animateRight() {
      if(!stop) {
         console.log('animateRight');
         $("#divTestBox3").animate({ "left" : "200px" }, 1000, animateLeft);
      }
   }

   function animateLeft() {
      if(!stop) {
         console.log('animateLeft');
         $("#divTestBox3").animate({ "left" : "20px" },1000,animateRight);
      }
   }        

});
</script>

</head>

<body>
  <div style="height: 40px;">
          <div id="divTestBox3" style="height: 20px; width: 20px; left: 20px; background-color: #89BC38; position: absolute;"></div>
  </div>
  <p>Press any key to start/stop the animation</p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
animateLeft
```

references is the function itself.

```
animateLeft()
```

is a **call** to the function `animateLeft` without any arguments. It evaluates to whatever that function returns.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `...animate(..., animateLeft())`, this is taking the **result of the animateLeft function** and passing it as an argument (this is why it executes immediately). When you use `...animate(..., animateLeft)`, this passes the **function itself** as an argument. In the latter case, jQuery uses the function as a completion handler, so it will be called when the animation finished.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass `animateLeft`, it refers to a function. But when you pass `animateLeft()`, it refers to the **result** of this function, so it executes immediatly when you call `animate()`.